When is the use of an em dash a bridge too far?
I can't seem to modify the following sentence to make it more correct without weakening its punch.

Viscerally, they are at our collective throat with our back against the wall—choking the consciousness, freedom, and life out of us.

Here’s why I think the above sentence might be correct: to get to the above sentence from the below one, I replace the semicolon with an em dash and use an elliptical phrase to omit “they are.” But is this a bridge too far?

Viscerally, they are at our collective throat with our back against the wall; they are choking the consciousness, freedom, and life out of us.

Another example of such a questionable bridge is the em dash in following sentence, which is also confusing me as to if this sentence is correct or not.

Of course, it can be exceedingly difficult to determine exactly what type a person is—who is a direct agent of the foundation, for example.

PS: Previous substitution of two hyphens for an em dash was just a mistake; I use two hyphens for an em dash in my drafts.

The first sentence looks fine. The second is a little confusing, not necessarily the fault of the dash. An em dash can stand without spaces, but 2 hyphens alone is a bit crowded.

' ...  they are at our collective throat with our back against the wall ' sounds rather misplaced-modifierish. But the em-dash (or, in the  UK at least, a spaced en-dash) would be fine; the semicolon also quite acceptable, but not two hyphens (some applications translate this to a dash, but others don't): ... wall—choking ... or ... wall – choking ..., or ... wall; choking ..., but not ... wall--choking ....

I used the two hyphens by mistake, replaced now with em dashes… silly me.

There's a similar but not identical question about "He has a sleeve of tattoos on his left arm—the most prominent being a picture of Bettie Page".

Use a comma... Two sentences with the same subject can be combined by reducing one of them to a participle clause (warning: grammar terms vary), like this: They are at our collective throat. + They are choking the consciousness, freedom, and life out of us. = They are at our collective throat, choking the consciousness, freedom, and life out of us.
